# Obscuring JNI Code From End Users in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I've written a bunch of android JNI code that I want to make into a library for a customer.  Obviously, I don't want the customer to be able to see my JNI code.  Is there a way I can include just the so file in a library project for them?

I've tried just using `System.loadLibrary(<library>);` but I get an Unsatisfied Link Error every time.

One thing that's worked, is I've just compiled my project and deleted all the c files.  I'm still able to use the .so file, but if I do a make clean, it deletes my so file and there's no way to recover it without the source.

In short, what I want is to be able to compile an so file on my own, and give it to my customer with some java code that interfaces with it.  I don't care if they see the java 'wrapper' source but I don't want them to be able to see the JNI code.  I also want them to be able to treat this library as they would any other (ie make cleans don't wreck it).

Thanks!

Comment: The .so file should be enough. Are you using gradle? It could be a naming convention problem? 
Can you give more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can include just the so file in a library project for them?

Package an AAR containing the libraries, and host the AAR as an artifact for your customers. See my [CWAC-AndDown library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown) for an example. The AAR will contain your `.so` files for whatever architectures that you are supporting, plus a JAR of the compiled Java code that provides your Java API to the native code.

> I also want them to be able to treat this library as they would any other (ie make cleans don't wreck it).

Well, by definition, **`make clean`** requires source. It also requires a makefile, which presumably you will not distributing, since that's useless without the source.